# Spark dataframe filter issue

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Coming from a SQL background here.. I'm using `df1 = spark.read.jdbc` to load data from Azure sql into a dataframe. I am trying to filter the data to exclude rows meeting the following criteria:

```
df2 = df1.filter("ItemID <> '75' AND Code1 <> 'SL'")
```

The dataframe ends up being empty but when i run equivalent SQL it is correct. When i change it to

```
df2 = df1.filter("ItemID **=** '75' AND Code1 **=** 'SL'")
```

it produces the rows i want to filter out.

What is the best way to remove the rows meeting the criteria, so they can be pushed to a SQL server?
Thank you

Comment: could you try something like `filter($"ItemIID" =!= "75" && $"Code1" =!= "SL" )`

Comment: i forgot to mention, i am doing this in python. i got invalid syntax on the $

Answer (score 2):

In SQL world, `<>` means `Checks if the value of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.`

The equivalent of it in spark sql is `!=`. Thus your sql condition inside filter becomes-

```py
# A != B -> TRUE if expression A is not equivalent to expression B; otherwise FALSE
df2 = df1.filter("ItemID != '75' AND Code1 != 'SL'")
```

`=` has same meaning in spark sql as ansi sql

```py
df2 = df1.filter("ItemID = '75' AND Code1 = 'SL'")
```

Comment: so i just tried converting to pandas dataframe and it is now working. pdf = df2.select("*").toPandas(), then pdf1 = pdf.loc[(pdf['ItemID']!='75') & (pdf['Code1'] != 'SL')], then convert back to spark for pushdown query df3 = spark.createDataFrame(pdf1). im not sure why the suggested syntax with "!=" above is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`&`** operator with **`!=`** in pyspark.

`<>` deprecated from python3.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(75,'SL'),(90,'SL1')],['ItemID','Code1'])

df.filter((col("ItemID") != '75') & (col("code1") != 'SL') ).show()

#or using negation
df.filter(~(col("ItemID") == '75') & ~(col("Code1") == 'SL') ).show()

#+------+-----+
#|ItemID|Code1|
#+------+-----+
#|    90|  SL1|
#+------+-----+
```